# ImageView alignment in custom notifcation layout

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement custom notification layout as described in examples.

```
 <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   >
   <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/image"
     android:layout_width="64dp"
     android:layout_height="64dp"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:scaleType="centerInside"
     />
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
     style="@style/Notification_Title"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     />
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title"
     android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
     android:paddingRight="10dp"
     style="@style/Notification_Text"
     />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

My layout also starts with ImageView on the very left position and need to be aligned as in default notifications.
Is there a default style that could be applied to the imageview or attribute value from which I could take default size?